Yocto module recipe with external extra srcs
I have a module that requires to use external source files(.cpp .c .h) from my module srcs.
In order to keep project sanity, I would like to have these external libraries srcs (used in my kernel module) compiled in my module but keeping the src externally.
This works with a makefile that links the srcs into my module folder and compiles and link them.
But now I would like to achieve that with yocto.
Any suggestions on best practices ?
This is how it would look like
├── external_srcs/
│   └──**some_lib_srcs**
│       └── dummy.c
│       └── dummy.h
├── project-spec/
│   └──meta-user
│   └── conf
│   └── **recipes-modules**
│       └── my-module
│           └── files 
│               └── main.c
│   └── recipes-apps
│   └── recipes-bsp

